# Replace tr shows wrong results while using jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to construct a tr and then replace with the first row of a html table.
I have a variable `newHeaderRow` in which i add jQuery objects and then i use `replaceWith` to replace the first row of the table with this variable.
The problem is that no dom elements is being added in the table however it just show

[object object] [object object][object object]

in the place of the first row

**To be specific**

I have 3 parts in my code where i create dom elements like

```
     result = $("<td/>",
     {
       align: "center",
       colspan: var1
    }).text("something");

    newHeaderRow += result;
```

and after some tds added in the newHeaderRow i use

```
     $('tr[class*="row#"]').eq(n)
        .replaceWith(newHeaderRow);
```

to replace the row.

I know that if i use plain javascript and i use something

```
result =  "<td  align='center'  colspan='" + countGroupBys + "'>" + "something" + "
  </td>"
```

and i add 3 strings in the newHeaderRow and then use replaceWith it will work.
But i do not want my code to have long and not easy to read strings.

In jQuery terms how can i pass the dom elements in the replace with and change the table?

Comment: `result` is a jQuery object, you can't concatenate it to `newHeaderRow` as a  string.

Comment: I recommend preparing a fiddle as an example

Comment: so i have to convert the jQueryObject to string   if that is possible and then added in result?

Comment: I'd probably make `newHeaderRow` a jQuery object and use `newHeaderRow.add(result)`.

Comment: Show declaration of `newHeaderRow ` as per [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to append the jQuery object like a string. Try to first convert it into a string. You do this by asking the inner **Node element** for it's **outerHTML**

This:

```
   newHeaderRow += result;
```

should become this:

```
   newHeaderRow += result[0].outerHTML;
```

```js
var newTds = "";
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var td = $('<td>', {
    align: "center",
    colspan: 1
  }).text('Header: ' + (i+1));
  
  newTds += td[0].outerHTML
}

$('#apple').replaceWith(newTds)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="apple">
      Apple
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Example in this fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/fghajk48/

Answer (score 0):

Just make the `newHeaderRow` a jQuery object and `append()` the cell objects to it

```
var newHeaderRow = $('<tr>');

// ......

result = $("<td/>", {
  align: "center",
  colspan: var1
}).text("something");

newHeaderRow.append(result);

//.....

$('tr[class*="row#"]').eq(n)
  .replaceWith(newHeaderRow);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't concatenate objects (since `$()` returns a jQuery object) as you do here:

```
result = $("<td/>",
{
    align: "center",
    colspan: var1
}).text("something");

newHeaderRow += result;
```

But, instead, you have to retrieve the content of your element, so you can change the last line with this one:

```
newHeaderRow += result[0].outerHTML;
```

Obviously, if you need to replace it with only one jQuery object, there's no need of the `[0].outerHTML`.
Another point: `.replaceWith()` will replace also the target element (the `<tr>` in this case), so make sure that `newHeaderRow` also includes the `<tr>` tag.

Comment: `result.html()` only returns what is inside `result`

Comment: Edited, replacing html(). Please see the code updated.